# Billing address does not have customer_id

Tags: magento2, orders, customer

Yesterday a customer called us regarding she could not place an order, but actually, the order has been placed and she was directed to the Review Order page with an error message

> "We can't place the order".

I checked the log file and found it is due to her billing address record in `qoute_address` does not have **"customer_id"** value so it could not pass the validate function in `QuoteAddressValidator.php`.

However, she did place the order as a registered customer and her shipping address record has customer_id.

When I checked the similar cases, I only found one happened last Oct. So it rarely happens and I even cannot repeat it.

Does anyone was faced with the same issue before or know where is the problem?

Thanks

[image]